# Disputed not an answer flags

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

I flagged two answers as "not an answer" but they were disputed. I've read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer) post but they don't fit int any section.

These are the answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25682109/2010566
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25682112/2010566

They are NOT answering the question(nor trying). OP is looking for a yes/no answer and the answers are improvements of OP's code.

Where they disputed because of having upvotes? Or am I missing some directives about this flag.

Comment: The first one is most definitely an answer

Comment: Indeed, the first one starts with "Yes it would work" ... Which sounds like an answer to a yes/no question. It then goes on to suggest improvements, so not sure what the problem is?

Comment: It is saying that the code will work, not if it will be executed each time.

Comment: @cowls That's the question that the OP has already stated that they've read

Comment: @cowls i've already read that and linked it in my question

Comment: They look as if they were trying to answer the question. Whether that try has failed, is something different, which requires specific field knowledge to jugde.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the provided examples may not be the correct answer to the questions, they are still answers.

Answers are not supposed to be flagged if they're "incorrect", because moderators aren't necessarily familiar with the subject of the question / answer.

If an answer is incorrect, downvote it.
If you feel especially helpful, also leave a comment on the answer explaining what's wrong/

Comment: They are not incorrect. They are not answering OP's question. If you think they answer the question, explain me how.

Comment: @javi They don't need to. If it **looks like they're answering a question**, relevant or not, *they are answers*. NAA flags are not designed to deal with incorrect or irrelevant answers, they're to deal with things that *simply aren't answers at all*, such as people posting things like "I have this problem too, did you manage to solve it?"

Comment: The posts were written with the intention of answering a question. As such, they _are_ answers. They may not answer the OP's question, but that's what you can downvote them for.

Comment: Ah! I thought they had to answer the question, not just being answers. So they could just type "It's 299,792,458 metres per second" and I shouldn't flag them.

Comment: @javi, yes, and that's crazy.

Comment: In that case, I think a flag might be in place. There's a difference between going absurdly off-topic, and just missing the point of the question.